# Reading multiple GZIP files on HDFS Using Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, hdfs

We have close to 1 million GZIP files scattered across a HDFS cluster. The files are stored inside sub-directories as well inside the HDFS. I am trying to process the files using pySpark. Since I need to retain the file name, I am using `wholeTextFiles` function. But Problem is its only iterating through one directory and not processing the rest of them. Also I would like to have the data inside RDD so that I can convert it apply some pattern matching on top it. Any idea how this can be achieved ? Thanks in Advance.

I have the HDFS on my local and I am trying to access the directories in the which are in following format.

```
rootDir
    -dir1
        -file1.gz
        -file2.gz
    -dir2
        -file3.gz
-file4.gz
-file5.gz
```

If I am trying to access a certain directory (as per the below example, dir1), I am not having any issues. All the files are getting loaded into the RDD.

```
spark_context = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate().sparkContext 
whole_html_files = spark_context.wholeTextFiles("localhost:9000/rootDir/dir1")
whole_html_files.map(some_processing_function_here).collect()
```

But what I am trying to achieve is to load all the files in `rootDir`. I have tried a couple of examples where I am using something like the one below. But It feels like I am not levering the actual power of spark

```
 hadoop = spark_context._jvm.org.apache.hadoop

 fs = hadoop.fs.FileSystem
conf = hadoop.conf.Configuration()
path = hadoop.fs.Path(hdfs_location)

for f in fs.get(conf).listStatus(path):
    print(f.isDir(), f.getPath(), f.getBlockSize())
```

Comment: Could you please add [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Just like that, it is difficult to understand what you want to achieve, what the paths look like and what is blocking you. also, add the code your tried and show the errors or misbehaviors

Comment: @Steven Updated as requested.